# Type boost::units::derived_dimension could not be resolved by Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, boost, eclipse-cdt, boost-units

I have defined a new derived_dimension type, specific_entropy_dimension, and a unit, specific_entropy in the header below.  This compiles just fine without warnings using g++, but, Eclipse CDT's indexer fails to resolve the type with the error:

> Type 'derived_dimension< length_base_dimension, 2, time_base_dimension,
>   -2,       temperature_base_dimension, -1 >::type' could not be resolved

Its the only error on my code, and I would like to resolve this so that I can get a 'clean' analysis.  What do I need to do to get CDT to resolve this type?

Units.h

```
#ifndef UNITS_H_
#define UNITS_H_

#include <boost/units/systems/si/energy.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/force.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/length.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/electric_potential.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/current.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/resistance.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/temperature.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/mass_density.hpp>
#include <boost/units/physical_dimensions/specific_energy.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/io.hpp>
#include <boost/units/conversion.hpp>
#include <boost/units/cmath.hpp>
#include <boost/units/derived_dimension.hpp>


using namespace boost::units;
using namespace boost::units::si;


typedef derived_dimension<length_base_dimension, 2, time_base_dimension, -2,
        temperature_base_dimension, -1>::type specific_entropy_dimension;


typedef ::boost::units::unit<specific_entropy_dimension, si::system> specific_entropy;


#endif /* UNITS_H_ */
```

Note, my header includes several more derived dimensions, but this demonstrates the problem.

Comment: That's not an error in your code, that's an error in some C++ parser implementation (CDT's). After all CDT is not a compiler.

Comment: Right :)  But I would like to have CDT not falsely report it

Comment: Not sure, but you might have better luck asking in their forums. Maybe they can easily fix it or there is some absolutely silly workaround.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, I will try that if nothing pans out here - ty